# When to define a new Sitecore event

Tags: configuration, events

There are numerous articles describing *how* to define and register a new Sitecore event:

- Sitecore Community Docs: [Sitecore Events](http://sitecore-community.github.io/docs/pipelines-and-events/events/)
- Old SDN (still actual): [Using Events](https://sdn.sitecore.net/articles/api/using%20events.aspx)

Are there any recommendations *when* to do so?

One can simply raise and handle [.NET events in code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/edzehd2t(v=vs.110).aspx). Sitecore events can be registered in a config file which *might* add some visibility and maintenance flexibility; Sitecore events have built-in support for *remote* communication. Any other reasons to define a Sitecore event?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One reason I can think of is *decoupling*

To subscribe to a regular .NET Event, I need to reference the assembly wherein it is defined. With Sitecore events, this is handled via configuration and therefore the Sitecore Configuration Factory. No reference to your assembly is necessary.

Comment: Make sense, thanks! Any other ideas?